# file reading line by line and printing not working on mac os but works fine in RHEL

Tags: c, file, line-by-line

The following code works in Linux but fails with a Segmentation Fault 11 on Mac OS (Catalina). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        FILE *fp;
        char *line;
        int i;
        int max_line = 1000;
        if (--argc > 0) {
                if ( (fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) != NULL) {
                        printf("File ptr:%p File Name:%s\n", fp, argv[1]);
                        while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
                                fputs(line, stdout);
                        }   
                        fclose(fp);
                } else {
                        printf("File cannot be opened:%s\n", argv[1]);
                }   
        }   
        return 0;
}
```

My input file:

```
0 1
0 2
0 5
0 6
5 3
0 4
```

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `line`.

Comment: `if (--argc > 0)` in combination with `argv[1]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Use `char line[MAXLINELENGTH];` after defining a macro `MAXLINELENGTH`

Comment: In your version, `sizeof(line)` is the size of a pointer, not the length of a string.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why it works fine in Linux though.